# How to traverse an array back n forth

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array something like this

```
$steps = explode("[;;]",$str);
```

So the $steps holds value that I have to use to show a step/step procedure in PHP .

The array looks like this

```
$steps = array('corredores' , 'something' , 'something'...and so one );
```

I am trying to display forms according to the value saved in the array . I am able to go forward using some validation but I have trouble in moving to the previous name in the array ,
for the first step I am doing something like this

```
$steps = explode("[;;]",$_POST['str']);
$x = explode("=",$steps[0]);
$pais1 = $_POST['pais'];
$cnt=0;
    switch($steps[0]){
        case 'categorias' :
        include  'obj/categorias.php';
                    //$step='categorias';
                    break;
        case 'corredores':
        include 'obj/corredores.php';
                    //$step='corredores';
                    break;
        case 'monedas':
        include 'obj/monedas.php';
                    //$step='monedas';
                    break;
        case 'location':
        include 'obj/location.php';
                    //$step='location';
                    break;
        default:
        break;  
    }
```

//Here I am trying to match the next value from the array that I will save in this post value on every step

```
    if(isset($_POST['next1']) &&$_POST['method'] != "fase1")
{
$cnt =$_POST['cnt'];
$cnt++;
$array_var = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["next1"]));
$steps = $array_var;
$pais1 = $_POST['pais'];

    $x = explode("=",$array_var[$cnt]);
include  'obj/'.trim($x[0]).'.php';
                //$step='categorias';   
}
```

So when I click on the next button of each file it goes to the next file in the array , But Now I need to add similar functionality to the previous button so that it goes back

The HTML content of every files has following structure

```
   <form method="post" action="./index.php" name="form_name">
    <table><tr><th>Some Name</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="previous"></td><td><input type="submit" value="next"></td></tr></table>
<input type="hidden" name="next1" value="<?php print base64_encode(serialize($steps))  ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pais" value="<?php echo $pais1?>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="cnt" name="cnt" value="<?php echo $cnt ?>" />
    </form>
```

Can any one give me some suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If I am not reading your code wrong, you already have an array of all the objects stored in `next1` and `cnt` as your currently counter. Essentially, what you need to do is to detect whether the user has pressed the Next or Previous button

```
<input type="sumbit" name="next" value="Next">
<input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous">
```

A form can have more than 1 submit button. Just be sure to name them differently. Then when you process your form:

```
if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
  // go on to the next object
  $cnt = $_POST['cnt'] + 1;

} else if (isset($_POST['previous']) {
  $cnt = $_POST['cnt'] - 1;
}

// retrieve object from array and include its file
```

It is **important** that you don't increment your `cnt` like above -- and only increment or decrement it before you press the buttons.

In short, change the value of `cnt` depending if the user presses Next or Previous.

Comment: okay let me try this , but I am using Jquery to submit the form when we press submit button will it effect any ways ?

Comment: If you are using form.seralize(), then it should work. If not, you have to remember to pass all the parameters to your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_search http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php for identifying acual step and then Add +1 for next step or remove -1 for the previous step